# How do i recover data from internal memory on a dead Xperia Z1?

Tags: internal-storage, data-recovery, internal-sd, sony-xperia-z1

I have a Xperia Z1 and when i try turning it on nothig happens. When i plug it in i get a flashing red LED. I have important photos on the internal memory inside it so i wonder if i can in some way recover the data from it.

EDIT: The phone is rooted.

Comment: Have you already checked with our [data-recovery tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info)? Also see: [Is it possible to recover data from internal memory?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/56797/16575) / [Recovering deleted photos on internal memory](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/112652/16575)

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not really possible for an end-user.  If the phone won't turn at all then the only way to recover data is to access the storage chip directly, using something like a JTAG setup.  Of course, it's possible that repairs might be possible (or moving the chip to another device), but it's impossible to say without more detail.

Comment: My phone doesn't turn on at all, and when I connect it to a pc it gets connected for about 4-5 sec and then disconnected in 1 sec and then connected again. So I can't use the pc to do something with it. What is a JTAG setup and how would I move the chip to another device?

Comment: @MartinBygdén Those are not beginner solutions; they are effectively unavailable to you.  You should approach a repair or forensics company that specializes in this if you really can't do without the data.

Comment: What do I need to do it?